# Date of last connection in Android studio app

Tags: android

I need the **date of the last connection**. When I enter again I have to see the last date that I entered in my app.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = new Date();

String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
```

I have this code but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your right you can just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`it looks like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Then you can save this value everywhere you want